# Combine multiple arrays using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have following code:

```
foreach(array_combine($names, $hashids) as $name => $hashid) {
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$counter.'</td>
<td>'.$name.'</td>
<td>'.$hashid.'</a></td>
</tr>';
}
```

Now I want to combine one more array and `iterate` it's values in `foreach`. That's three arrays in a foreach statement. can anyone help me in adding it. Like how can we add multiple `arrays` in foreach statement.

For example I want something like:

```
foreach(array_combine($names, $hashids, $photoids) as $name => $hashid => $photoid) {
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$counter.'</td>
<td>'.$name.'</td>
<td>'.$hashid.'</td>
<td>'.$photoid.'</td>
</tr>';
}
```

But above code gives me `error`. The error I get is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in /homepages/4/d864452909/htdocs/public_html/app/index.php on line 58

Comment: share what this returns `print_r(array_combine($names, $hashids, $photoids) );`

Comment: @AlwaysSunny I have added in question.

Comment: no you didn't I meant print the result of those three array combine before `foreach` loop AND share with us

Comment: @AlwaysSunny It doesn't return anything for three array values. But for two arrays combine it returns following `Array ( [Sample] => JdpmLLdx5me7K [Big Buck Bunny 60fps 4K - Official Blender Foundation Short Film.mp4] => lWJQjwrVRZdXn )
`

Comment: **Exactly**, what I wanted to point you that array_combine doesn't do combine of 3 array at once. so you need to share the full code with us so we can help you. :) see here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: @AlwaysSunny So how can I use `three arrays in foreach statement`? Will `array_map` work

Comment: what is inside the `$photoids`? as per your comment I can see the first array_combine contains the name and hash id, now you want to add the photoids with it and  iterate with foreach. That's why asking to share full code e.g $names, $hashids, $photoids at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I will do this way with simple `foreach()` loop,

```
<?php
$names = ['Sample','Big Buck Bunny 60fps 4K - Official Blender Foundation Short Film.mp4'];
$hashid = ['JdpmLLdx5me7K','lWJQjwrVRZdXn'];
$photoids = ['url_1_of_the_image','url_2_of_the_image'];
$result = [];
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = array(
        'name'  => $names[$key],
        'hashid' => $hashid[$key],
        'photoid'    => $photoids[$key],
    );
}
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$k.'</td>
         <td>'.$v['name'].'</td>
         <td>'.$v['hashid'].'</td>
         <td>'.$v['photoid'].'</td>
         </tr>';
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/61Tcr **OR** https://3v4l.org/133c3

Comment: @Andy glad it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the objects as below

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($names as $value) {
    array_push($arr, $value);
}

for($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
  foreach($arr[$x] as $y => $val) {
    $arr[$x] = (object) array_merge((array) $arr[$x], (array) $hashids[$x]);
    $arr[$x] = (object) array_merge((array) $arr[$x], (array) $photoids[$x]);
  }
}

for($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$arr[$x]->counter.'</td>
<td>'.$arr[$x]->name.'</td>
<td>'.$arr[$x]->hashid.'</td>
<td>'.$arr[$x]->photoid.'</td>
</tr>';
}
```